# How to catch multiple attributes and it's arguments using __getattribute__ or similar method?

Tags: python, attributes

I know we can catch any attribute using `__getattribute__`. But I need to catch all corresponding attributes and still not leave the scope of `__getattribute__`. Attributes can be in the form of list of strings.

For example:

Suppose `my_object` is an object of `my_class`. And user calls `my_object.attr_a.attr_b`, then I want to get a list `['attr_a', 'attr_b']` and control to do something after execution of above line without any interruption.

Also, it'd be great if I can also get `*args` and `**kwargs`.

I've tried following ways of implementing `__getattribute__` method of `my_class`:

```py
attr_list =[]
def __getattribute__(self, attr):
    global attr_list
    attr_list.append(attr)
    exec(attr + " = my_class()")
    return eval(temp)
```

While this works great, it requires me to return from scope of `my_object.__getattribute__` to `attr_a.__getattribute__` to `attr_b.__getattribute__` and then `__main__`. What I want is to, remain in the scope to `my_object.__getattribute__`.
Any help would be really appreciated. Different type approach is also welcomed.

Comment: In `my_object.aatr_a.attr_b`, `attr_b` is not an attribute of `my_object` - it's an attribute of `my_object.attr_a` - why should `my_object` return that attribute? Also, using `exec` and `eval` as you are in the code right now is just asking for security bugs. Those are usually never a good idea.

Comment: Thanks @rdas! Yes `attr_b` is attribute of `my_object.attr_a`, my bad. I unintentionally mistyped it. I know using eval and exec is not a good practice, but that was what I was able to think of. Is there any way I could get `[attr_a, attr_b]` and do something after execution of `my_object.attr_a.attr_b` without program interruption?

Comment: Again, you don't seem to have understood what `my_object.attr_a.attr_b`. It's equivalent to: `t = my_object.attr_a; val = t.attr_b`.  So `attr_b` is not supposed to be an attribute of `my_object`. So it makes no sense to try and access it from that class